# "Low Quality Posts" audit ignored filter

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was reviewing Low Quality Posts and had applied a filter to see
answers only. So, when a question popped up, it was immediately obvious
that it had to be an audit. (The 8 upvotes were a bit of a clue, too.)

I realize the purpose of LQP audits is just to make sure the reviewer is
paying attention, but to make the audit minimally challenging, I think
the choice of audit should take the user's filter settings into account.

Thoughts?

Comment: relevant MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204639/audits-bug-in-the-filtered-review-queue (albeit only a sentence of opinion actually relevant to this question)